# Coloring SpatialLines by attribute in R?

Tags: r, symbology, legend, line, color-ramp

I have a `SpatialLinesDataFrame` dataset of rivers in R. The dataset consists of lines (river segments) with a "Turbidity" attribute. I want to create a map and legend, where:

- Turbidity between 0 and 10 is yellow
- Turbidity between 10 and 20 is orange
- Turbidity between 20 and 30 is red

Here is my sample dataset:

```
library(sp)

#create the sample SpatialLines with 3 lines and 1 attribute
x1 <- c(15.10,15.20, 15.25)
y1 <- c(48.9, 49.1, 49.0)
Line1 <- Line(cbind(x1, y1))
LineString1 <- Lines(list(Line1), ID=1)

x2 <- c(15.25,15.21)
y2 <- c(49.0, 49.12)
Line2 <- Line(cbind(x2, y2))
LineString2 <- Lines(list(Line2), ID=2)

x3 <- c(15.21,15.12)
y3 <- c(49.12, 49.05)
Line3 <- Line(cbind(x3, y3))
LineString3 <- Lines(list(Line3), ID=3)

spLines <- SpatialLines(list(LineString1, LineString2, LineString3))
spLinesDF <- SpatialLinesDataFrame(spLines, data.frame(Turbidity=c(5, 24, 16), row.names=c(1, 2, 3)))

#this is the color breaks that I want to use in map and legend
breaks = c(0, 10, 20, 30)
colors = c("yellow", "orange", "red")

#this doesn't assign the correct colors to my line values
plot(spLinesDF, col=colors)
```

What commands do I use to match the color breaks (0, 10, 20, 30) with the colors(yellow, orange, red) and with the Turbidity attribute values in my map and in the legend?

I know that for raster I could use simple commands like:

```
brk <- c(0, 10, 20, 30)
col <- c('yellow', 'orange', 'red')
plot(raster, col=col, breaks=brk)
```

But for SpatialLines, the `plot` doesn't appear to support the color breaks parameter.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `cut` to build the breaks, and auto-coercion of the cut factor to integer:

```
plot(spLinesDF, col=colors[cut(spLinesDF$Turbidity, breaks)])
```

Comment: For adding the legend, the following commands worked:      `legend("topleft",legend=levels(cut(linPtsF$Turbidity, breaks)), lty=c(1,1,1), col=colors)`

Answer (score 3):

Here is one suggestion:

```
require(ggplot2) #function fortify, function ggplot
require(plyr) # function join

  spLinesDF@data$id = rownames(spLinesDF@data) #join id column to data slot on SpatialLinesDataFrame
  df = fortify(spLinesDF,region="id") #create data frame from SpatialLinesDataFrame
  df = join(df, spLinesDF@data, by="id") #add Turbity information to the data frame object

  df$Turbidity=cut(df$Turbidity,breaks=c(0,10,20,30)) #set breaks

  axis.size = 14 #set axis.size
  axis.label.size = 11 #set axis labels size
  legend.size = 13 #set legend size

#plot graph with R package ggplot
ggplot(data=df,aes(x=long,y=lat, colour=Turbidity)) +
      geom_path() +  
      scale_colour_manual(values = c("yellow","orange", "red")) +
      xlab("Longitude") + ylab("Latitude") +
      coord_equal() + 
      theme_bw() + 
      theme(panel.border=element_rect(color="black"),
            panel.grid.major=element_blank(),
            panel.grid.minor=element_blank(),
            axis.title.y=element_text(size = axis.size, vjust=+0.2),
            axis.title.x=element_text(size = axis.size, vjust=-0.2),
            axis.text.y=element_text(size = axis.label.size),
            axis.text.x=element_text(size = axis.label.size),
            legend.title=element_text(size = legend.size))
```

[image]

Answer (score 2):

I always appreciate the application of "ggplot" but this can easily be done using the low level plotting functions available in R. I like @mdsumner's solution because it is so efficient. However, you do not have clear control of a specific color pallet.

A simple approach is to use "ifelse" to create a vector of equal length to your variable, containing the desired colors.

Here is an example.

```
require(sp)

#create the sample SpatialLines with 3 lines and 1 attribute
L1 <- Lines(list(Line(cbind(c(15.10,15.20,15.25),c(48.9,49.1,49.0)))), ID=1)
  L2 <- Lines(list(Line(cbind(c(15.25,15.21),c(49.0, 49.12)))), ID=2)
    L3 <- Lines(list(Line(cbind(c(15.21,15.12),c(49.12, 49.05)))), ID=3)
      L <- SpatialLinesDataFrame(SpatialLines(list(L1, L2, L3)),           
              data.frame(Turbidity=c(5, 24, 16),row.names=c(1, 2, 3)))

# Create a color vector that is the same length as y
( y.col = ifelse( L$Turbidity <= 10, "yellow",
            ifelse( L$Turbidity > 10 & L$Turbidity <= 20, "darkgoldenrod1",
              ifelse( L$Turbidity > 20, "red", NA) ) ) ) 

# Plot the sp object passing the color vector to the col argument
plot(L, col=y.col)
  box()
    legend("topleft",legend=c("low","med","high"),
           lty=c(1,1,1),col=y.col[c(1,3,2)])
```